# How does Orchard get away with no call to RenderBody?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, orchardcms

I’ve been dissecting the Orchard CMS rendering and view engine in an effort to understand how it’s put together. I have discovered that neither RenderBody nor RenderSection are ever called. It is my understanding that the Razor view engine requires a call to one or the other.

What is it that gets around the requirement that RenderBody or RenderSection have to be called or an exception is thrown by Razor?

Is it the fact that there’s a custom view engine (ThemeAwareViewEngine)? If so, how does it handle parsing Razor syntax to generate the content?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually the other way around. `Razor` itself doesn't require that `RenderBody` be called it's the `RazorViewEngine` that has this requirement. There can definitely be another view engine that uses Razor that has a completely different way of working. Take a look at https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine or https://github.com/Buildstarted/RazorSharp I've also written a markdown view engine that uses razor for some simple layouts.

From reading the source it looks as if they've created a few custom view engines. Their `RazorViewEngine` replaces the base class for razor generated files with their own custom `WebViewPage` which has a method `Display` of which `Zone` is an alias for. This is what allows them to render child views in addition it seems as if there are several types of Zones within the `LayoutAwareViewEngine` such as `DocumentZone`, `ContentZone` and so forth.

So in the end they've done a lot of custom code.

Comment: So I see. Let me digest this. Thanks!

Comment: It took quite a bit of digging to figure it out but it looks really neat. Definitely going to check it out some more so thanks for the question :)